# What does it mean for a sequence of functions $f_n$ to increasse to $f$?

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying Measure Theory using Folland and came across this phrase: $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of functions that increases to $f(x)$ almost everywhere (with respect to a measure). What does it mean for the sequence $f_n(x)$ to increase to $f(x)$?

**Attempt**: Given any fixed $x$, the sequence of real numbers $\{ f_n(x) \}$ is such that $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$, and it converges to $f(x)$. That is, the sequence of function converges pointwise to $f$.

Almost everywhere means that the statement in my attempt is true only for $x$ in sets with non-zero measure. Is my understanding correct? He is simply talking about pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could also include the possibility that $f_{n} \le f_{n+1}$ a.e. for a given $n$. That would be okay, too. Even if the exception set were different for each $n$, the union of all of these could serve as an exceptional set of measure 0, outside of which $f_{n}(x) \le f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Quick response.

You are right about $f_n(x) \le f_{n+1}(x)$

Almost everywhere means, the set of points where it does *not* converge has measure zero.